# Permission to execute (actually SELECT) a user defined function to EVERYONE

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have created a UDF, now this fetched information from some restricted database(s) and also reads extended properties of restricted database(s). We wish to keep restricted database(s) as is, i.e. that is no direct access to those databases.

However, we would like everyone (I mean every authenticated SQL user) to be able to run this scaler UDF like this:

SELECT somedatabase.dbo.udf_getInfo()

So in other words, only scaler function udf_getInfo should be accessible to everyone, and this scaler value function will read some DB information, that user executing have no direct access.

Comment: Do all the objects that the UDF refers to exist in the same database and schema as the UDF? Have a read of this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: UDF refer to extended property on master database, and a table within same (itself) database. We do not wish to expose both of these directly to everyone. Hence the scaler UDF

Comment: So the table should be OK but you'll need to enable cross database ownership chaining for the extended property. Post the code you have tried and the error/undesired behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

```
use YourDbName
GO

-- only one of these is correct 
GRANT SELECT on dbo.udf_getinfo() TO public 
GO
-- only one of these is correct 
GRANT EXEC  on dbo.udf_getinfo() TO public 
GO


-- YOU MUST HAVE PERMISSION also - AND - you need to have the GRANT on it to give the permission.
```

Comment: GRANT SELECT is throwing error. GRANT EXECUTE might work as this is UDF and not Table/View. I will try that, and let you know.

Comment: I would not recommend granting to public except for base intrinsic scenarios.   GETDATE()   or  IsLastDayOfYear() might be for public.  If there was anything remotely non public data then I would have a role for all users and grant to that role.

Comment: I agree, I am also not hugely in favour of granting public access to SQL Server. In fact that's my second worry, I wish to grant access to only those, who can login access to server (SQL or Windows Authentication). Any suggestion?

Comment: They will have to have a login to that database to be part of public.  But it is all logins to that database.   public does not include people you did not allow in your database, so it is what you describe.

Comment: If only one of them is correct, why keep us in suspense with your answer?

Comment: To Clarify Michael12345 question (it is a relevant question).  User Defined Functions live in SQL Server like two different types  - A: as a TABLE - so it behaves kind of like a TABLE or View.     or...  B: as a "stored procedure".   Functions that are like stored procedures are not "anything goes" - they should be able to be used "inline" in the select - similar to a traditional IIF().  (immediate IF).